# Spikes in rotanional rate from MPU-6050

Tags: filters

I am reading sensor data with my Raspberry Pi from the MPU-6050 sensor, which has an accelerometer and an gyroscope. I am using an adjusted version of the i2cdevlib and I'm taking the measurements from the FIFO buffer with the DLP (digital low pass) enabled. I don't know if this is important, but the sensor output is the following (when not moved):
[image: sensor]

The X-Axis are seconds, the Y-Axis is the gyroscope output (32 bits) divided through (2¹⁶ * 16.4). It seems that the 17th bit from right is toggling from 0 to 1 all the time. This error occurs on all three axis.
Is this an usual error? Is there a filter?

Comment: What bit is toggling? In the numbers before or after your processing? How can the 17th bit be toggling if the unit only uses 16Bit ADCs?

Comment: The i2cdevlib has a function to read a 32bit int from the FIFO buffer, which also delivers 32bit data.

Comment: How do you know this is an "error" rather than expected noise or a noise-filtered offset in the actual hardware's LSB?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an error, but how do I filter it out?

Comment: Well, to me this looks like normal jittering in the least significant bit. But it is difficult to give an analysis if you can't find out which (hardware) ADC-bit is toggling. Whatever your i2clib says, the ADC is 16Bit and if you read 32Bits from it, it does some processing, maybe scale it up to 32 which would explain why the 17th bit is toggling.